Error on flags page
When I try reviewing my outstanding flag status , I go to my profile page and hit the "flags" link.
I am observing a bug, as I am only getting to a blank page

Welcome to Meta SE. FYI, I believe this problem is very likely related to the problem stated in “Top users” and “Learn more ...” pages are empty, with my answer there giving some more details specifically about what your question is reporting on.

Thanks @JohnOmielan, in my case it only happens with the flags, so slightly different

You're welcome. As indicated by both myself and Martin R. in comments below my linked answer, both the initial problem reported by him and the flag screens issue are no longer a problem for either of us. As such, you may wish to check to see if the flags screen is working properly for you now as well.

@JohnOmielan that was quick,  yes it works. Should I delete this question

Thanks for confirming the problem is resolved for you as well. Although the underlying issue was likely the same for both the problem reported in the other question and here, so your question could be considered somewhat of a duplicate, since you just got an answer from a staff member, Adam Lear, I suggest you don't delete your question.

Sorry about that, we deployed a change to rendering user cards that contained a bug that seems obvious in hindsight but went unnoticed.
The issue has been fixed and all pages rendering user information should be working as normal.
